# IIS - tempory config file overwrite DefaultAppPool.config

Tags: iis, web-config, windows-server-2012-r2

I'm working aroung IIS config files.

[image]

I want add some IIS IP address restrictions at server level, that spread over all the IIS appPolls

[image]

If I work with IIS Manager all work fine, I'm able to add any config settings. But if I want modify/add them directly on .config file it is no possible.
I can see that the settings made by IIS Manager are written on a temporary .tmp file under C:\inetpub\temp\appPools and then overwritten on DefaultAppPool.config under C:\inetpub\temp\appPools\DefaultAppPool

[image]
[image]

If I try to manual modify DefaultAppPool.config it don't take effect on IIS Manager and if I make any changes on IIS Manager it is overwritten. If I try to manual modify the tmp config under C:\inetpub\temp\appPools I'm informed that the file is in use.

[image]

I've also try to work with applicationHost.config under C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config, but it does not seem to match the configuration displayed on IIS Manager.

**So how can I edit the IIS configuration file manually at the server level?**
I've to add a lot of IP restrictions and the only way is to add them directly on .config file.
Very thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

That is the temporary file. if you want to change the iis configuration at the server level then you could modify the iis applicationhost.config file.

ApplicationHost.config is the root file of the configuration system when you are using IIS 7 and above. It includes definitions of all sites, applications, virtual directories and application pools, as well as global defaults for the web server settings (similar to machine.config and the root web.config for .NET Framework settings).

Open notepad as administrator and open applicationhost.config

add below code in the config file:

```
    <ipSecurity allowUnlisted="true">
            <add ipAddress="192.168.2.52" allowed="true" />
        </ipSecurity>
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/planning-your-iis-architecture/introduction-to-applicationhostconfig

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but as I wrote above I tried to work around the applicationhost.config file, the one in the folder C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config, but it does not seem to match the configuration displayed on IIS Manager.
Maybe I have to see in a different folder?

Comment: @scippy do you want to apply setting at server level or site level? after applying setting you could try to restart the server.

Comment: I want add them at Server Level

Comment: @scippy then you could try as suggested in the post. by opening notepad as administrator and add the code in applicationhost.config file under   <security>

Comment: I've tried to add a IP to ban to the applicationHost.config but after restarted IIS it was no added to IISManager. See the image [LINK](https://www.dropbox.com/s/x648am2712rzgpa/Post-08.07.2020.Screenshot_1.jpg?dl=0)

Comment: @scippy download process monitor and set filter for applicationhost.config like this [image](https://i.imgur.com/bwpsz3l.png) and check which location configs file affected when you try to add IP and domain restriction in iis manager.

Comment: Thanks, I've checked with process monitor and all refers to C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config\applicationhost.config but if I open it with notepad++ no one entry is present. It's really crazy

Comment: @scippy try to open the notepad++ with an administrator and then open applicationhost.config

Comment: Nothing change, applicationhost.config is different from IIS Manager

Comment: My server is based on Microsoft Hyper-V machine, could this be the problem?